# Connect to remote PostgreSql database using Powershell

Tags: postgresql, powershell, odbc

I'm trying to connect to a remote PostgreSql database using powershell.  This is my first time using powershell so I'm sorry if this is a noob question.  This is my Code:

```
$DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE}:Server=$MyServer;Port=$MyPort;Database=$MyDB;Uid=$MyUid;Pwd=$MyPass;"
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString;
$DBConn.Open();
$DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();
$DBCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mytable;";
$DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
$DBConn.Close();
```

When I run this I get "Exception Calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".  I've downloaded and installed the pgsqlodbc driver but I'm still getting this error.  Does anyone have any ideas how I could fix this?  I have searched the internet and I'm really not getting anywhere at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the DSN exists in ODBC data source. If not you have to create one going to 'Control Panel', 'Admin. Tools', 'Data Sources (ODBC)'. Then select 'Add User DSN'-
Select the PostgreSQL driver, and fill in your server and database details.
Test connection to check is all ok!

Answer (score 8):

Consult: https://odbc.postgresql.org/
Download: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

Data sources (ODBC) on Windows: *Start → Search → odbc → User DSN → Add/Configure*

[image: Screenshot ODBC Driver Setup]

Example :

```bsh
$MyServer = "<ip>"
$MyPort  = "5432"
$MyDB = "<database>"
$MyUid = "<user>"
$MyPass = "<pass>"

$DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=$MyServer;Port=$MyPort;Database=$MyDB;Uid=$MyUid;Pwd=$MyPass;"
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString;
$DBConn.Open();
$DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();
$DBCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tb_module;";
$DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
$DBConn.Close();
```

Comment: This works for me but my result is array which had header FieldCountr and 5 rows with number 3 there. The result is 3 column with 5 rown but how can I assign it to array?

Answer (score 8):

You can use psql which comes with postgresql if you happen to have postgresql installed on your client

```
$dburl="postgresql://exusername:expw@exhostname:5432/postgres"
$data="select * from extable" | psql --csv $dburl | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

You must have psql in your path or reference it, its within e.g. C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin. Should be able to type "psql" and see output within powershell.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have a typo in your connection string after Driver declaration.
There is a double colon instead of a semicolon :)

Wrong:

```
{PostgreSQL UNICODE} : Server
```

Correct:

```
{PostgreSQL UNICODE} ; Server
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, I thought the Postgresql ODBC driver was installed, but it wasn't.  I finally got it to work after finding this site:  http://code.google.com/p/visionmap/wiki/psqlODBC  Then I followed the instructions above.  it works.

Thanks for all the help.