# Powershell with PostgreSQL SELECT query returns wrong results

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I'm currently working with Powershell and PostgreSQL and I encountered weird results. I also tried searching for similar questions but couldn't find one.

So, below is my Powershell script config for PostgreSQL which I got from here: [Connect to remote PostgreSql database using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217650/connect-to-remote-postgresql-database-using-powershell)

```
$MyServer = "MyIP"
$MyPort  = "5432"
$MyDB = "MyDB"
$MyUid = "MyUser"
$MyPass = "MyPass"

$DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=$MyServer;Port=$MyPort;Database=$MyDB;Uid=$MyUid;Pwd=$MyPass;"
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString;
$DBConn.Open();
$DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();
$DBCmd.CommandText = "SET SCHEMA 'MySchema'; SELECT * FROM Myclients;";
$DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
$DBConn.Close();
```

It's a pretty straightforward SELECT query, nothing fancy. Connection is working but the SELECT results returns this:

```
FieldCount
----------
        12
        12
        12
        12
        12
        12
        12
        12
        12
        12
```

Not really sure why it happen. Maybe someone can enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I figure this out. You explicitly need to use the dataset command and adapter. So, this will answer the problem above. After opening, you add the following:   $DBCmd= New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
    $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    (New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($ds) | out-null
    $conn.close()
    $ds.Tables[0] 

I'll just keep this question for others who might encounter the same problem.

Comment: Even better would be if you wrote this as an answer rather than a comment.