# How to resolve garbled code when using powershell to execute psql and the Copy command?

Tags: powershell, psql

I'm writing powershell script to copy "csv" from client machine to remote postgre database table with psql copy command.

The copy command executed successfully, but some Japanese characters have become garbled.

I have set the encoding for client and console stdin and stdout, but garbled code still occurred.

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
[System.Console]::InputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
$env:PGPASSWORD = 'pwd';
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem .\Import -Filter *.csv){
    $table = $file.BaseName
    $Truncate_Sql = "truncate table $table;"
    $Result = & psql -h 10.0.xxx.xx -d db1 -U user1 -w -c $Truncate_Sql
    Write-Host $Result  $table  "Ok."
    $Result =   Write-Output (Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Encoding utf8) | & psql -h 10.0.xxx.xx -d db1 -U user1 -w -c "set client_encoding=UTF8;COPY $table FROM STDIN WITH(FORMAT CSV,HEADER TRUE, ENCODING 'UTF8')"
    $Result
}
```

For example, the csv(utf8 encoding) content looks like the following

```
header1,header2
1001,その他
```

When copied to postgre, I use pgAdmin to view the table data. It shows:

| header1 | header2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | ??? |

Comment: Please describe "garbled" in great detail.

Comment: Passing special (Japanese) characters to and from an external command is almost asking for trouble. Instead, I would try an ODBC connection. See: [Connect to remote PostgreSql database using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42069324/1701026)

Comment: It does not seem like PowerShell is the issue here. It is more likely your database causing that issue. Please take a look at [multibyte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/multibyte.html) and [encoding when creating a table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-createdatabase.html). Kanji is UTF-8 but many languages are. The application needs to know that you are using Kanji characters and not Latin characters. Font and rendering are completely different.

Comment: @iRon But, I use bash to do the same thing on linux, everything is Ok. I just want to use powershell to get the same result.

Comment: The question marks indicate that the FONT that is being used is not compatible with the text.  Use a different FONT.  Is text Unicode or 8 Bit?

Comment: `$OutputEncoding` defaults to `ascii` in PowerShell 5. Run `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` to ensure `UTF8` 
in pipeline to `psql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question. I confused the Postgre SQL `COPY` command with psql `\COPY` instruction.

Actually, I need to use `\COPY` instruction to execute copy command, then I can directly copy from *file* instead of writing to `stdin`.

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
[System.Console]::InputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
$env:PGPASSWORD = 'pwd';
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem .\Import -Filter *.csv){
    $table = $file.BaseName
    $Truncate_Sql = "truncate table $table;"
    $Result = & psql -h 10.0.xxx.xx -d db1 -U user1 -w -c $Truncate_Sql
    Write-Host $Result  $table  "Ok."
    $Result = & psql -h 10.0.xxx.xx -d db1 -U user1 -w -c "\COPY $table FROM $($file.FullName) WITH(FORMAT CSV,HEADER TRUE, ENCODING 'UTF8')"
    $Result
}
```